# How to make NIC team come up on boot in RHEL 7

Tags: networking, rhel, lacp

To configure networking on RHEL 7, I created a JSON file for teaming, then ran these commands:

```
ip link set down eno1
ip link set down eno2
ip link set down eno3
ip link set down eno4
teamd -g -f lacp.conf -d
```

Also I created ifcfg files for VLANs and ran this command:

```
systemctl restart network
```

After that, everything works more or less as expected, but the problem is that this is not persist between reboots, so I have to do this every time after start-up.

How can I fix this problem? I expect this commands to be executed just once, and then I want this settings to persist between reboots.

==========================================================

I've tried to apply suggested fix and these questions appeared:

1. I've created `ifcfg-team0` file, and content is:

   ```
   DEVICE=team0
   DEVICETYPE=Team
   ONBOOT=yes
   BOOTPROTO=none
   TEAM_CONFIG='{"device":"team0", "runner": { "name": "lacp"...
   ```

Should I remove "device" section, so change to `TEAMCONFIG='{"runner": { "name": "lacp"...` because I already have `DEVICE=team0`? Or it's ok to mention it twice?

2. My `ifcfg-eno1` file contain:

   ```
   HWADDR=...
   TYPE=Ethernet
   BOOTPROTO=dhcp
   DEFROUTE=yes
   PEERDNS=yes
   IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
   IPV6_INIT=yes
   IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
   IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
   IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
   IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
   IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
   NAME=eno1
   UUID=e656...
   ONBOOT=no
   ```

Should I really remove almost everything from it? In particular am I really should remove `UUID`, `NAME` sections and substitute this file to what documentations suggests? :

```
    DEVICE=eth1
    HWADDR=D4:85:64:01:46:9E
    DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
    ONBOOT=yes
    TEAM_MASTER=team0
    TEAM_PORT_CONFIG='{"prio": 100}'
```

Or I should keep both files? Just name them for example `ifcfg-eno1` and `ifcfg-eno1Team`

3. When executing this: `systemctl start network.service` I receive such error:

   ```
   Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.  Unit network.service entered failed state.
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create a new file in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` directory called `ifcfg-team0` that looks like this:

```
DEVICE=team0
DEVICETYPE=Team
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=1.2.3.4
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
TEAM_CONFIG='{"runner": {"name": "lacp"}, "link_watch": {"name": "ethtool"}}'
```

Obviously you need to change the IP address and netmask appropriately.

Then in the same directory, change all of the `ifcfg-eno[1-4]` files to look like this:

```
DEVICE=eno1
HWADDR=00:11:22:33:44:55
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team0
TEAM_PORT_CONFIG='{"prio": 100}'
```

As above, your local files will differ a bit, because you will need to preserve the existing `HWADDR` setting.

This is [straight out of the manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Configure_a_Network_Team_Using-the_Command_Line.html#sec-Creating_a_Network_Team_Using_ifcfg_Files).

The `ifcfg-team0` file refers to the `lacp.conf` file you have already created. I do not see in the manual how it finds that file, however. Perhaps `teamd` remembers it from your earlier manual configuration, or perhaps you have to put it in a common directory.

Anyway, once this is configured, you say `ifup team0`, and the teamed NIC group will all come up together. The individual interfaces need to be down at the start, but you won't need to do anything special to ensure that on boot, since they're now marked as part of a NIC team. The OS's boot configuration will realize that it shouldn't bring those four interfaces up individually, but only as part of the NIC team.

---

All of the above assumes you have disabled [NetworkManager](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/003jan05/features/networkmanager/) and gone back to the good old way of configuring networking on Red Hat type Linuxes:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
$ sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
$ sudo systemctl start network.service
$ sudo systemctl enable network.service
```

This is often a good idea on servers, particularly when their network configuration starts getting tricky, as with LACP. NetworkManager solves a lot of problems, but it often does so with a desktop-focused slant that is inappropriate for servers. For instance, it solves the automatic WiFi to Ethernet transitions common with laptops. Servers typically have static network configurations, so NetworkManager can end up just getting in the way.

Still, if you find yourself wanting to stick with Red Hat's defaults, they do cover that alternative [a few sections earlier in the manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Configure_a_Network_Team_Using-the_Command_Line.html#sec-Configure_Network_Teaming_Using_nmcli).

Comment: Thanks, i will try soon. So it seems `10.5.2` doesn't persist between restarts, but `10.5.3` persist? BTW you likned `10.5.2`, but you supposed to link to `10.5.3`? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Configure_a_Network_Team_Using-the_Command_Line.html#sec-Creating_a_Network_Team_Using_ifcfg_Files

Comment: @javapowered: Yes, thanks for the manual link fix. Also see the NetworkManager material I just added.

Comment: thanks, i'm trying, added couple of question to my initial post, i would appreciate if you review.

Comment: for example why there are no `TYPE=Ethernet` section in `ifcfg-eno1`. how OS will know that this is ethernet?

Comment: now it works more or less, but when executing `ifup team0` i've received `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` message twice

Comment: thanks, i rebooted and everything started including VLAN's

Comment: Regarding your new questions, you are expected to intelligently merge the suggestions into your existing files, not just blindly blast them with canned example text.

Comment: Actually I "blindly blast them" and it works. Probably some problems will arise later...

Comment: now I have such error `"enable network.service
network.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig network on
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.` and so on.

Comment: it was suggested to execute `systemctl mask NetworkManager` at first (before stop). I didn't tested this yet

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the above configuration give works perfectly fine with NetworkManager and does not need legacy network services. See also the link to the RHEL manual above.

Comment: Also ditching NetworkManager messes up the boot order and your team is not taken into account of the network-online.target. This means for example NFS mounts aren't unmounted soon enough during stop/reboot